# Is there a reason fbclid prevents website fetching data via MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess

When a user gets linked to my website from Facebook it seems that the 'fbclid' that gets added to the URL stops the site from fetching any data from the MYSQL database.

All the text on my website is stored on a MYSQL database as it's in two languages, as well as a lot of the content.

Everything works when opening with this link;
https://vecinosyamigos.your360tours.com/events

But not this one;
https://vecinosyamigos.your360tours.com/events/?fbclid=IwAR35sQ04ye0_enrjFAvHj6SZuwtU6gjS-zRkHkuRU1LPyLzxPg6ZyowFswM

With this link the main page works but not the 'events' section;

https://vecinosyamigos.es/fbclid=IwAR3-4hs0OcSRL3DwtFbDNEujyvEfTP8zq7k6tClBFEGe1rDpB6sVdBAkxH0

I've tried implementing the javascript solution from the questions below, which successfully removed the section from the URL but didn't solve the problem;

[What is fbclid? the new facebook parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847475/what-is-fbclid-the-new-facebook-parameter/52877205#52877205)
[The new parameter FB adds to external links (fbclid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914875/the-new-parameter-fb-adds-to-external-links-fbclid)

The site is using a PHP framework, this is my .htaccess file in the public directory;

```
vecinosyamigos
-app
-public
  .htaccess
```

.htaccess file;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

There is a solution for `.htaccess` file changes as found in the answer on here website but I'm not familiar enough with them and I am unsure how to change it keeping the settings I have.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see any issues with the fbclid link

Comment: @aynber I added another link for the site with a little explication

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this, without down voting with no comment, this was an issue with cache. I reset it by sending a variable with the stylesheet.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/css/style.css?v=1">
```